# How to create acknowledgeable warnings alongside of errors with spring-boot + thymeleaf + jpa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, hibernate-validator

Showing **errors** with thymeleaf forms works **fine**, when the validation of a field fails.
However, I am **struggling to implement "warnings**". For example:

- Booking Date: If it's more than a year in the future, a warning should be created, which can be waived/acknowledged. If the date is in the past an error should be created.
- Booking Offer: If the dollar value is greater than 1000 then a warning should be created, which can be waived/acknowledged. If the dollar value is <= 0, then an error should be created.

I tried to implement the warning system using **validation constraints** (jakarta.validation.Constraint) the same way (hard) validations are implemented.
However, I haven't found a way to **distinguish between "errors" and "warnings" in the thymeleaf template to make the "warnings" acknowledgeable** (e.g. showing an additional clickable check mark)

Also, I fail to see how the **information** that a "warning" was acknowledged can be **passed back to the Validator/Constraint**, so that the data can be stored once the user has **fixed all errors and acknowledged all warnings**.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class BookingHeader {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
        @FutureOrPresent
        @OpenBookingPeriodConstraint(message = "{BookingHeader.BookingDate.OpenBookingPeriodConstraint}")
        private Date bookingDate;
        
        @Positive
        @OfferPriceTooHighConstraint
        private int bookingOffer;
}
```

```java
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = OpenBookingPeriodValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface OpenBookingPeriodConstraint {
       String message() default "Booking is too far in the future";
        Class<?>[] groups() default {};
        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

```java
public class OpenBookingPeriodValidator implements ConstraintValidator<OpenBookingPeriodConstraint, Date> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(OpenBookingPeriodConstraint constraint) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(Date dateField, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(new Date());
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 365);
                return dateField != null && dateField.before(cal.getTime());
        }

}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 container justify-content-center card">
            <h1 class ="text-center"> Create Booking</h1>
            <div class = "card-body">
                <form th:action="@{/booking/add}" th:object="${bookingHeader}" method="post" id="contactForm1" data-bs-target="#main_menu_users">
                    
                    <div class ="form-group">
                        <label for="bookingDate">bookingDate</label>
                        <input type="date" th:field="*{bookingDate}" id="bookingDate" placeholder="bookingDate" class="form-control">
                        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('bookingDate')}" th:errors="*{bookingDate}"></span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class ="form-group">
                        <label for="bookingOffer">bookingOffer</label>
                        <input type="number" th:field="*{bookingOffer}" id="bookingOffer" placeholder="bookingOffer" class="form-control">
                        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('bookingOffer')}" th:errors="*{bookingOffer}"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Errors show correctly]

[image: These messages though should be warnings that can be skipped/acknowledged]